# Can't create an array in a function

Tags: python, arrays, function

When I run the code below, I expect the variable 'a' to contains a list of IPs from 192.168.1.1-192.168.1.254, but when I run a 'print(dir(a[:]))', it throws the error:

**ERROR:**

```
["[IPv4Address('192.168.1.254')]"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 27, in <module>
    print(dir(a[:]))
TypeError: 'NoneType'
```

**CODE:**

```
    python3
    import ipaddress
    import csv

used_ips = []

def csv_dict_reader(file_obj):
    """
    Read a CSV file using csv.DictReader
    """
    reader = csv.DictReader(file_obj, delimiter=',')
    for line in reader:
       used_ips.append(line["ip_address"])
       print(used_ips)

def ip_list(network_addr):
   ips = []
   addr = ipaddress.ip_network(network_addr)
   for i in addr.hosts():
      ips.append([i])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("data.csv") as f_obj:
        csv_dict_reader(f_obj)

a = ip_list('192.168.1.0/24')
print(dir(a[:]))
```

Comment: return ips at the end of ip_list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
python3
import ipaddress
import csv

used_ips = []

def csv_dict_reader(file_obj):
    """
    Read a CSV file using csv.DictReader
    """
    reader = csv.DictReader(file_obj, delimiter=',')
    for line in reader:
       used_ips.append(line["ip_address"])
       print(used_ips)

def ip_list(network_addr):
   ips = []
   addr = ipaddress.ip_network(network_addr)
   for i in addr.hosts():
      ips.append([i])
   return ips

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("data.csv") as f_obj:
        csv_dict_reader(f_obj)

a = ip_list('192.168.1.0/24')
print(dir(a[:]))
```